# Getting length of string by typecasting it to int pointer in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, typecast-operator

Going mad with string pointers, please help.
Here is my question:

```
static int ByteOrder(
        char **charPtrPtr,
        long length,
        char *destPtr)
{
    char *endPtr = destPtr + length;

    while (destPtr < endPtr)
    {
        *destPtr++ = *((*charPtrPtr)++);
    }
    return 0;
}

int LenGet( char **charPtrPtr,
               long *lengthPtr)
{
    if (ByteOrder(charPtrPtr,
                sizeof(long),
                (char *)lengthPtr) != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("charPtrPtr: %s, lenPtr: %ld\n", *charPtrPtr, *lengthPtr);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *charPtr = "ffffff";
    long length = 0;

    LenGet(&charPtr, &length);
    printf("charPtr: %s, len: %ld\n", charPtr, length);
}
Output:
   charPtrPtr: ff, lenPtr: 1717986918
   charPtr: ff, len: 1717986918
```

In the above sections of code, what is the function ByteOrder does?
I tried searching the answer for it, could not get it directly. I assume it copies all the stirngs from charPtrPtr to destPtr. And in the function LenGet, the lengthPtr returns the length of the string. Trying to understand this logic. Spent enough time in searching for it and now posting it here. If any links available for the same that helps me understanding this logic, please help me by posting it here or explaining it. Thanks, Denise.

Comment: `printf("charPtrPtr: %s...", charPtrPtr...);` is *wrong* and leads to *undefined behavior*. Same with the `lengthPtr` argument and the `"%d"` format.

Comment: Also for `*length` in the `printf` function at the bottom, that should be `length`. Please compile your code with all warnings turned on and fix the warnings first. And make sure to copy-paste properly.

Comment: While addressing the previous comment, instead of adding pointer to charPtrPtr and lengthPtr, added it to charPtr and length. Edited the same now, thanks.. @Evert

Comment: Just take your *actual* code, compile it (with warnings fixed), then *copy-paste* that code into the question. The above code still doesn't produce anything like the output you're showing. (Format characters for `long`s are `"%ld"`, btw).

Comment: copy pasted my actual code, changing %d to %ld. Thanks @Evert

Comment: It's still mysterious to me *what* the code actually does. It appears to estimate the size of a `long` type in a very complicated manner. Nothing to do with determining the byte order. And on my system, where a `long` is 8 chars, `charPtr` is overrun, since it contains only 6 "f"s. As I don't see any `==` comparison, I doubt there is any way to actually check for and determine the byte order.

Comment: If you don't require any of this code, I'd advise to ditch this and never look at it again. It doesn't appear to do anything useful, and does that in a convoluted manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139210/discussion-between-denise-and-evert).

Comment: The code copies the first `sizeof(long)` characters (here 4 characters) of the string "ffffff" into the variable `long length`. Notice: 1717986918 = 0x66666666 and 0x66=102 which is the character 'f'. Further the code increments the `charPtr` 4 times (aka sizeof(long) times) therefore it only prints the string as "ff".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above sections of code, what is the function ByteOrder does?

The function does two things:

1) It copies `length` characters from a source string to a destination string

2) It advances the pointer to the source string by `length`

It can be shown like this:

[image]

So the idea of the function is pretty simple. Copy N bytes and advance the pointer N positions - probably to indicate the next bytes to be processed.

The function could be rewritten to something like:

```
static int ByteOrder(
        char **charPtrPtr,
        long length,
        char *destPtr)
{
    memcpy(destPtr, *charPtrPtr, length); // Copy characters
    *charPtrPtr += length;                // Advance source pointer

    return 0;  // Don't know why the function returns a fixed value
}
```

The rest of the code is horrible and probably violates strict aliasing.

Anyway:

The code copied the first 4 bytes of the source string into the integer variable `length` (and advanced the source string pointer by 4).

Notice that length = 1717986918 = 0x66666666 and 0x66=102 which is the character 'f'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am neither aware of this piece of code which is not so easy to understand but its an already existing function used by various existing features in a project. Needed to understand the same hence posted here. I was always getting the length of the destPtr in lengthPtr, with the real time usage. Hence decided to put it in stack overflow thinking if its an existing method of conversion then I too can undertand.